# Problemas con validación en dos input files con PHP

Tags: php

Hola gente tengo un problema muy raro, resulta que tengo dos campos input file que sube dos imágenes, frente y dorso del DNI, cuando quiero editar la información del usuario y cambiar la imagen 1, se cambia la imagen 1 pero desaparece la dos, y si quiero cambiar la 2 se cambia la 2 y desaparece la 1, y si actualizo solo los datos desaparecen las dos imágenes,  hay algún problema con el if que no estoy viendo, ¿alguien me puede ayudar?

les dejo mi código de edición:

```
$fotofrente = $_FILES["fotofrente"];
$fotodorso = $_FILES["fotodorso"];

if (empty($fotofrente) && empty($fotodorso)) {
        echo 'los dos estan vacios';
        //aca no actualizo los campos de las fotos
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE tarjetas SET nombre_tarjeta=UPPER('$nombre_tarjeta'), tipo_tarjeta=UPPER('$tipo_tarjeta'), titular_tarjeta=UPPER('$titular_tarjeta'), banco_tarjeta=UPPER('$banco_tarjeta'), numero_tarjeta='$numero_tarjeta', venc_tarjeta='$venc_tarjeta', cod_seguridad='$cod_seguridad', dni_titular='$dni_titular' WHERE id_tarjeta='$id_tarjeta'");
        mysqli_close($conn);
        header('Location:cargar-tarjetas.php');
    
} else if (empty($fotofrente) && !empty($fotodorso)) {
    echo 'fotofrente esta vacio, fotodorso tiene contenido';
    foreach($_FILES["fotodorso"]["name"] as $pos => $archivo) {
        $fotodorso = time() . ($_FILES["fotodorso"]["name"][$pos]);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fotodorso"]["tmp_name"][$pos], "uploads/" . $fotodorso);
        $fotodorso = "uploads/" . $fotodorso;
        //aca actualizo solo la foto de atras
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE tarjetas SET nombre_tarjeta=UPPER('$nombre_tarjeta'), tipo_tarjeta=UPPER('$tipo_tarjeta'), titular_tarjeta=UPPER('$titular_tarjeta'), banco_tarjeta=UPPER('$banco_tarjeta'), numero_tarjeta='$numero_tarjeta', venc_tarjeta='$venc_tarjeta', cod_seguridad='$cod_seguridad', dni_titular='$dni_titular', fotodorso='$fotodorso' WHERE id_tarjeta='$id_tarjeta'");
        mysqli_close($conn);
        header('Location:cargar-tarjetas.php');
}
} else if (!empty($fotofrente) && empty($fotodorso)) {
    echo 'fotodorso esta vacio, fotofrente tiene contenido';
    foreach($_FILES["fotofrente"]["name"] as $pos => $archivo) {
        $fotofrente = time() . ($_FILES["fotofrente"]["name"][$pos]);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fotofrente"]["tmp_name"][$pos], "uploads/" . $fotofrente);
        $fotofrente = "uploads/" . $fotofrente;
        //aca actualizo solo la foto de frente
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE tarjetas SET nombre_tarjeta=UPPER('$nombre_tarjeta'), tipo_tarjeta=UPPER('$tipo_tarjeta'), titular_tarjeta=UPPER('$titular_tarjeta'), banco_tarjeta=UPPER('$banco_tarjeta'), numero_tarjeta='$numero_tarjeta', venc_tarjeta='$venc_tarjeta', cod_seguridad='$cod_seguridad', dni_titular='$dni_titular', fotofrente='$fotofrente' WHERE id_tarjeta='$id_tarjeta'");
        mysqli_close($conn);
        header('Location:cargar-tarjetas.php');
            
}
} else if (!empty($fotofrente) && !empty($fotodorso)) {
    echo 'los dos tiene contenido';
    
    foreach($_FILES["fotofrente"]["name"] as $pos => $archivo) {
        $fotofrente = time() . ($_FILES["fotofrente"]["name"][$pos]);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fotofrente"]["tmp_name"][$pos], "uploads/" . $fotofrente);
        $fotofrente = "uploads/" . $fotofrente;
            
    foreach($_FILES["fotodorso"]["name"] as $pos => $archivo) {
        $fotodorso = time() . ($_FILES["fotodorso"]["name"][$pos]);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fotodorso"]["tmp_name"][$pos], "uploads/" . $fotodorso);
        $fotodorso = "uploads/" . $fotodorso;
        
        //aca actualizo todo
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE tarjetas SET nombre_tarjeta=UPPER('$nombre_tarjeta'), tipo_tarjeta=UPPER('$tipo_tarjeta'), titular_tarjeta=UPPER('$titular_tarjeta'), banco_tarjeta=UPPER('$banco_tarjeta'), numero_tarjeta='$numero_tarjeta', venc_tarjeta='$venc_tarjeta', cod_seguridad='$cod_seguridad', dni_titular='$dni_titular', fotofrente='$fotofrente', fotodorso='$fotodorso' WHERE id_tarjeta='$id_tarjeta'");
        mysqli_close($conn);
        header('Location:cargar-tarjetas.php');
            
}
}
}
```

Comment: Cuando actualizas solo los datos (sin fotos) y dices "desaparecen las dos imágenes", te refieres a que los campos de la tabla quedan en blanco o null verdad? no que desaparezcan tus imágenes de uploads. que pasa si comentas todos los **if** y solo actualizas los datos (sin los campos de fotos)

Comment: Si comento no voy a poder actualizar las imágenes, solo se actualiza los datos

Comment: Ese es el punto. Me imagino que si estas en un ambiente de pruebas no importa. Pero creo que la respuesta de Jhon tiene bastante razón

Comment: Gracias a todos ahí pude resolver como decía Jhon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siguiendo la logica de tu problema, me resulta obvio que **siempre** se dispara el "IF" que maneja las dos imagenes...
Esto se debe a que el array de $_FILES nunca esta totalmente vacio, por lo que tu condicion siempre es verdadera...
Esto explicaria, el "porque" se te borran las imagenes (en realidad las reemplaza por "nada")...

Cambia tu condicion para checar el tamaño del archivo ($_FILES["nnn"]["size"]) de tal manera que tu condicion sea sobre el tamaño (mayor a cero)...

Tambien agrega algo de validacion, ya que asi como esta tu codigo es vulnerable a inyeccion...

Espero esto resuelva tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si tenias razon, ahi le cambie a  case empty($fotofrente['name'][0]) && !empty($fotodorso['name'][0]):, y ademas cambie el if por un switch.